# JSTL Issue Closing tags must match opened tags?

Tags: jsp, foreach, jstl

Receiving the title error from the following code, have no idea why though?

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>

<c:if test="${fn:length(art.articles.GALLERY) > 0}">
  <div id="slidewrapper">
    <c:set var="additionalJS" scope="request"/>${additionalJS}
      <script language="javascript">
      // global variables and arrays
      var slideShowImages    = new Array;
      var slideShowImageAlts = new Array;

      <c:set var="galleryArray" value="${art.articles.GALLERY}"/>
      <c:set var="galleryLength" value="${fn:length(art.articles.GALLERY)}"/>

      <c:forEach items="${galleryArray}" varStatus="status">

        <%-- Reverse the order --%>
        <c:set var="article" value="${galleryArray[galleryLength - status.count]}">

        <c:if test="${status.first && not empty article.img.IMAGE.filename}">
          <c:set var="firstSlide" value="${av.imageURL}${article.img.IMAGE.relative_url}/${article.img.IMAGE.filename}"/>
          <c:set var="firstAlt" value="${article.img.IMAGE.alt_text}"/>
        </c:if>

        <c:if test="${status.count == 2 && not empty article.img.IMAGE.filename}">
            <c:set var="secondSlide" value="${av.imageURL}${article.img.IMAGE.relative_url}/${article.img.IMAGE.filename}"/>
        </c:if>

        <c:if test="${not empty article.img.IMAGE.filename}">
            slideShowImages[${status.index}] = '${av.imageURL}${article.img.IMAGE.relative_url}/${article.img.IMAGE.filename}';
            slideShowImageAlts[${status.index}] = '${article.img.IMAGE.alt_text}';

            var galleryImage${status.index} = new Image();
            galleryImage${status.index}.src = '${av.imageURL}${article.img.IMAGE.relative_url}/${article.img.IMAGE.filename}';
        </c:if>
      </c:forEach>
      </script>
    </c:set>
    <div id="slidealt" <c:if test="${empty firstAlt}" > class="transparent"</c:if>>${firstAlt}</div>
    <div class="slideimage" id="imageLayer1"><img src="${firstSlide}" id="slideImage1" /></div>
    <div class="slideimage transparent" id="imageLayer2"><img src="${secondSlide}" id="slideImage2" /></div>
  </div>
  <div id="slidecontrols">
    <c:forEach items="${art.articles.GALLERY}" var="article" varStatus="status">
      <c:if test="${status.first}">
        <a href="#" onclick="zrSlideShowLogic(imageNumber - 1); return false;" id="previousButton" class="slideprevious" title="Previous">Previous</a>
      </c:if>
      <a href="#" onclick="zrSlideShowLogic(${status.index}); return false;" id="galleryPage_${status.count}" <c:if test="${status.first}">class="slidecontrolsactive"</c:if>>${status.count}</a>
      <c:if test="${status.last}">
        <a href="#" onclick="zrSlideShowLogic(imageNumber + 1); return false;" id="nextButton"  class="slidenext" title="Next">next</a>
      </c:if>
    </c:forEach>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</c:if>
```

Complete error is:

```
ProcessRequest - url=/dealer-locator/store-detail.jsp. Exception message: .renderPage(): /includes/gallery.jsp:33: expected at . Closing tags must match opened tags. 31: galleryImage${status.index}.src = '${av.imageURL}${article.img.IMAGE.relative_url}/${article.img.IMAGE.filename}'; 32: 33: 34: 35:
```

Comment: Unrelated, but yikes. Also, `new Array` isn't really canonical.

Comment: Supporting old code, trying my best to clean up this rats nest =( It is `luckily` going away very soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, forgot to close this

`<c:set var="article" value="${galleryArray[galleryLength - status.count]}"/>`